# solve $ y = (A+B^{-1})x $ for $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, inverse

I wish to solve numerically for $x$,

$$ y = (A+B^{-1})x $$

with $A, B$ positive definite. So,

$$ x = (A+B^{-1})^{-1}y $$

I would like to avoid calculating $B^{-1}$ since that's generally bad.

This question seems unusually short. I can provide extra info if needed.

Comment: You can just do an intermediate solve:
Solve $Bw=x$, then $y=Ax+w$

Comment: That sounds like just the kind of thing I need, but I don't know what that is. Can you elaborate? Maybe I'm just dense.

Comment: Sorry about that... I always forget get that <return> submits a comment... editted above.

Comment: @JohnSalvatier  Could you clarify whether you are solving $x$ for a known $y$, or solving $y$ for a known $x$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is indeed what I meant.

Comment: You want to solve for $Ax + B^{-1}x = y$ i.e. you want to solve for $$(BA+I)x = By$$ If $\Vert BA \Vert < 1$, then we have $$x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k (BA)^k By$$ This can be truncated to get arbitrarily accurate results. IF you truncate after $r$ terms the cost to evaluate this goes as $\mathcal{O}(rn^2)$ where $n$ is the size of the matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I think for my purposes, I can just solve 
$$(BA+I)x = By$$
$$x = (BA + I)^{-1}By$$
Give that as an answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: Or is there some reason that doesn't work?

Comment: @JohnSalvatier But that is computing an inverse, that you said you didn't want to do.

Comment: I can just calculate $solve(BA+I, By)$, no?

Comment: @JohnSalvatier If you use $\text{solve}(BA+I,By)$, you might need to form $BA$ first, which is again expensive.

Comment: @JohnSalvatier You could use iterative methods to solve for $x$. For example, the Jacobi and Gauss–Seidel methods for solving a linear system converge if the matrix is strictly (or irreducibly) diagonally dominant. You can also use the SOR method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take Marvis' answer one step ahead.
You want to solve $(BA+I)x=By$. Because $BA+I$ is positive semidefinite, you can use conjugate gradient. The only operation you need is matrix multiplication and convergence is guarantee to an accurate solution within a finite number of steps.